# How Do I Know What Is In A Public Docker Image?

Tags: docker

Is there any way to know what is in a public image other than downloading it and checking it out manually?

e.g. I can see on dockerhub various java images and a various ansible images, I would have to download quite a lot to determine which one to use and if any had both

The dockerfile lists some info but often there is inheritance and so you can't see all the info.

Is there anything that lists all the contained packages or an online service that lets you try them out without downloading the whole image?

Comment: I think you already answered your own question. You can either look at the Dockerfile or download & run the image to investigate. There's no global "package list" since there's no global Docker package manager. It depends which distribution is running inside the container. Generally speaking, you'll only want a single service per container - like MySQL. If you need something more custom, you should probably write your own Dockerfile based on one of the base distributions like Alpine or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

[MicroBadger](https://microbadger.com/) lists the `docker history` of a Docker image and shows matching base images (with their layers as well). E.g. https://microbadger.com/images/ansible/ansible